# Generating spatially correlated samples from a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab

I am trying to generate some spatially correlated samples from a multivariate normal distribution following this algorithm

Compute Cholesky factorization Q=LL'
Sample z~N(0,I)
Solve L'v=z
Computer x=mui+v
Return x

I have a spatial grid of 10x10 cells.
I wanted to know how can I check if the data is correlated from x. Can I plot something to verify if the data that I obtain is correct?